# setTimeout only running with a console.log in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following code on a Meteor app

```
Template.timer.helpers({    
       currentTime: function(){
            //keep the current time stored in the session
            timeout = Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
              Session.set("now", new Date());
            }, 1000);
            console.log(Session.get('now'));
});
Template.timer.events({
    'click': function(){
        //some code
        Session.set("now", new Date());
        //some more code
    }
});
```

When there is a click event I get multiple timeouts running simultaneously, even though I'm only updating the Session once.

But, if I remove console.log in timer.helpers, then the setTimeout doesn't update the Session at all (only the Click does).

What am I missing?? Is there a better way to keep a current (reactive) client time stored?

Comment: By the way, just to be clear, the above code is template code, so they are executed on the client, not on Meteor server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update a client session with the latest client time every second, you can use Meteor.setInterval instead and set it up after the template has rendered.  For example:

```
Template.timer.rendered = function() {
  Meteor.setInterval( function() {
    Session.set("now", new Date());
  }, 1000);
};

Template.timer.helpers({
  currentTime: function() {
    return Session.get("now");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, for those reading after, the two other answers have a lot more explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the essence of reactivity.

When a function which reruns reactively (which includes helper functions and autorun blocks) gets the value of a [reactive object](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity) anywhere within its code, the function is registered as a dependency for that object.  When the value of the object changes, the function's computation will be invalidated by the change of value, and the function will rerun itself.

So what happens here is that the `console.log` is, most importantly, `get`ting the value of your session variable, which makes the helper rerun every time it's `set`.  However, it also sets a timeout callback which itself `set`s the value of the variable (to a value which is guaranteed to be different as it's the current time), which means the helper function will call itself again as soon as the timeout callback has run.

If you remove the `console.log`, you also remove the `Session.get`, which will remove the dependency and the helper will no longer rerun when the value of the Session variable is changed, whether by the timeout callback or elsewhere.

There are a lot of resources on the web to help understand reactivity, which is probably the most fundamental concept in learning Meteor.

https://meteorhacks.com/journey-into-meteors-reactivity.html
http://manual.meteor.com/#deps-transparentreactiveprogramming
http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/meteor-reactive-data-types/

Comment: Thanks so much for the rundown of why it was breaking, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
            //keep the current time stored in the session
            timeout = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
              var se = Session.get("now");
              if(se === true){
                se = new Date();
                console.log(se);
              }else{
                 console.log("until click i start")
              }
            }, 1000);
            //console.log(Session.get('now'));
  });


Template.timer.events({
    'click': function(){
      console.log("clicked")
        Session.set("now",true);
    }
});
```

Try this code, this is what i change.

First, we just set a `true/false`, session inside the event, just to let know when the user, click the button.

and later, we put the the session inside a `Tracker.autorun(function(){})`, with auto run we look for any change on the sessions, and remove the timeout for a interval, docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers)

third, on the timeout variable, we look for variables changes, if `"now" === true`, we start the timer, if not, we send a friendly `console.log`.

That works form me.

Comment: Thanks for this Ethaan, only reason I didn't pick it was that Manto had simpler code, unless this one is better or more reliable in some way that I'm not seeing?